# How can I put an array into a method?

Tags: arrays, methods, prime-factoring

I have to find the LCM of two integers using the prime factors method and function calls. 
I'm up to making a function to find the prime factorization of the first number, but I'm getting errors at `int x = first_number;` and with `System.out.print(primeFactorization)`.

This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lcm {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int first_number;
        int second_number;

        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        first_number = reader.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter another integer: ");
        second_number = reader.nextInt();
    }       
    public static int primeFactorization(int[] pfArray) {

        int counter = 0;

        pfArray = new int[10];  //created array in memory 

        int x = first_number;

        for(int i=2;i<=x;i++){
            while(x%i==0){
                x=x/i;
                pfArray[counter] = i;
                ++counter;
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<counter;i++){
            System.out.println(pfArray[i]);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(primeFactorization);
}
```

I am just starting to learn Java, so please answer in very basic terms!
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The variable `first_number` is declared in the first method and so cannot be used within the second method unless you pass it in as a parameter.

The only thing called `primeFactorisation` is the method. System.out.println requires an object (a variable) as its input. So you can't do it like that.